# svn commit is not working

Tags: linux, svn

When I use

```
svn st -u
```

I see the following pending file as

```
? Pairwise.py
Status against revision:   1003
```

Then when i use

```
svn commit
```

nothing happens. When I check again

```
svn st -u
```

I see the same like before. Please let me know what's the problem. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` means that you haven't run svn add, so svn won't do anything with it.

Comment: when i run svn add, it gives me the following msg: 
svn: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: Not enough arguments provided

Comment: the problem was in svn add. Thanks